# etymology of predation and predating?

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences, latin

Do *predation* and *predating* share a common etymology?

*Predation* seems to imply that one species holds precedence over another species in the food chain, whereas *predating* seems to imply that one event holds precedence over another in the linear progression of time.

Both words obviously share the prefix *pre*, but my question is more about the *dat* part of each word.

What is the origin of *dat* in early English or in Latin or the Romance languages Latin gave birth to?

And how does that origin explain the meaning of the modern words *predation* and *predating*?

Comment: They have the same relationship as *antedating* has with *auntie-dating*: none whatsoever. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Predation," meaning to preying upon, comes from the Latin *praedari* meaning to plunder, which is itself from "praeda," meaning booty.

"Predate" is from the Lating *pre* (before) + *datum*.  The latter is the past participle of the verb *do* (*dare*, *dedi*, *datum*), meaning to give.  This was used in the standard Roman style of dating letters with the formula *data epistola Romae*, "letter given at [i.e, delivered to] Rome."

References: *Cassell's Latin Dictionary, The Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology*

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to answer.  Please see comment I wrote at end of nohat's answer.  I wrote it there so as to also be able t ping Cerberus.

Answer (score 0):

The word *predation* comes from the Latin *prædatio* meaning "taking of booty" which comes from *præda* meaning "booty". This is to say the word "predation" does **not** have the prefix *præ-* meaning "before".

Only *predating* comes from the Latin *præ-* meaning "before".

Comment: Actually, *praeda* comes from *prae-hend-o* (fun fact: *-hend-* is related to *-gin* in *begin*), so both words contain the prefix *prae-*.

Comment: @Cerberus Your comment illustrates why I do not find these answers to be satisfying. I see prae-hend-o and prae-datum.  I also see the concept of cyclical time that was prevalent in antiquity, so that there were primordial, metaphysical connotations to coming before.  Things were swallowed up in attempts to get back to the origin, like a predator swallows prey.  Virgil wrote the Aeneid to show that Octavius' consumption of all power in Rome was valid because he was re-manifesting Aeneis.

Comment: @Code: It is true that the Ancients, like the Humanists in some ways, entertained a cyclical view of history; but that was only one of several views that vied for dominance, depending on the genre, the period, etc. While both words ultimately contain the same *prae-*, the *-dat-* is entirely different in each word: they come from entirely unrelated roots (Proto-Indo-European *~\*dʰe-* in *predating* and *\*gʰ-n(e)-d-* in *predation*). It is possible that *prae-* in *praeda* primed some connotation of anteriority to a Roman, but I have to say I doubt whether it was significant in context.